# Scrolling to multiple anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, anchor

I have a glossary page, that work with anchors. When you click on "A" link it go to #A, when you click on "B", it go to "#B". But this jump to the anchor and i would like it to scroll.

How can i did this width javascrit? Can i put a javascript in html onclick?

This my actual code:

```
<?php $categories =  get_categories('child_of=100&hide_empty=0'); 
        foreach  ($categories as $category) {
            //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
            echo '<h2><a name="' . $category->name . '">'.$category->name.'</a></h2>';
            echo '<ul>';
            $posts = get_posts(array('cat' => $category->term_id, 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'glosario', 'showposts' =>-1, 'post_status' => 'publish,future,draft'));
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';  
            }  
            echo '</ul>';
        } ?>
          <div id="scrollablemenu">
<?php $cats = get_categories( 'child_of=100&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    echo '<a href="#' . $cat->cat_name . '" class="scrollablemenubutton" class="scroll">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
}
?>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});
 });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [jQuery ScrollTo() plugin](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/);

Very easy to implement, and you don't have to re-invent to wheel.

Here is a basic example of how to use scrollTo:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('body').scrollTo('#anId', 1000);
});
```

See live demo [here](http://codepen.io/trufa/pen/Lxmjo).

If you want to use it with onclick, see demo [here](http://codepen.io/trufa/pen/imFag).

Note that where is says `#anId` it could be anything, for example the name of the link or whatever you want, you just reference it like this:

```
$(this).whatEverFunctionOrValueYouWant();
```

Comment: i dont kwon how to implement. And i have to use other [plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll)

Comment: @Genethic I'll give you an example in a minute, give me a second, why do you want localScroll, that plugin is to be used **in addition** to the one I'm suggesting.

Comment: If i can use only use the first one, better. I looked like it had to use it.

Comment: i am trying with this: onclick="$.scrollTo($("#' . $cat->cat_name . '",800));" but it dont work. What i am doing bad? Excuse my english please.

Comment: @Genethic see my edit. Please tell me if you have any doubts.